Why does this simple thumbnail script work on PC browsers and not work on Android browsers?
can someone tell me why this simple thumbnail script works on PC browsers and not on Android browsers? Opened from Chrome or Firefox on my phones it shows a transparent png image.
<input type="file" id="upload"/>
<img id="thumbnail"/>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('upload');
var img = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
input.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = url;
    var snapshot = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 150;
    canvas.height = 150;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    };
    video.addEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
});
</script>

Ten days ago I think it was working in Android as well... Can anyone find out what happened and give me some advice?
